# Cryptic-ception

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

I thought of this a few days ago and I figured I'd give a try.

I have written a cryptic clue, then taken said clue and written a cryptic clue about that cryptic clue.

> ["Ignored projectile", pronounced this disregarded batty host (9, 4)] (5)

The enumeration inside the brackets ([ ]) is for the words that are currently seen. The enumeration outside is for the answer of the outer (inner?) cryptic.

**My question is simple, what's the final answer?**

---

PS: *Please give feedback on the structure of my Cryptic Clues as I'm still learning on how to build them properly*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inner cryptic:

> **DISMISSED SHOT**    (Ignored projectile [*def.*]; pronounced this [DIS, *hom.*] +
>                 disregarded [MISSED] + batty host [SHOT*])

Outer cryptic:

> Dismissed shot. (5)
>  **FIRED**    (Dismissed [*def.*]; shot [*ddef.*])

> *PS: Please give feedback on the structure of my Cryptic Clues as I'm still learning on how to build them properly*

These both looked pretty good to me, nicely done. :)

Comment: I figured this would get solved quickly, good job.